# cargar componente hasta abrir el modal

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un modal que se abre con un botón, en dicho modal hay un componente pero se carga el componente y sus funciones antes de abrir el modal.

**MODAL**

```
 <div id="modalTransportation" className="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onClick={this.deleteData}>
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body" steps={this.steps()}>                                   
                                    <div className="tab-content mt-2">
                                        <div className="tab-pane fade show active" id="infoPanel" role="tabpanel">
                                            <Transportation  datas={this.state.datas} dataIndividualRes={this.state.dataIndividualRes} dataTrans={this.state.dataTrans} idreserva={this.state.idres} infoTrans={this.state.infoTrans} transportation={this.state.transportation} lng={this.state.lng} />                                            
                                        </div>                                                            
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**BOTON**

```
<button className="dropdown-item btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTransportation" className="dropdown-item btn text-md" onClick={(e)=> {this.getIDReservationTrans(e, item.iddef_reservation);}}><i className="fas fa-bus-alt pr-2"></i>Transportation</button>
```

el componente es "Transportacion" esto se carga en la vista y al presionar el boton se abre el modal pero al hacer eso ya las funciones que hay en el componente se cargaron por lo que no tiene algunos datos de los que se pasan por props y marca error

Comment: Que error te aparece cuando corres esto?

Comment: Al parecer se cargan las funciones que hay en el componente al mismo tiempo y al no tener los props necesarios no funcionan